# Only first row selectable in md-datepicker when using md-max-date in firefox

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

While using the angular material datepicker in my application and i am able to select dates only in the first row. The datepicker works as expected in chrome but not in firefox.

The problem happens only when md-max-date is specified.I want the maxdate to be the current date.

This is what I am doing

HTML:

```
<md-card>
 <md-card-content>
   <h4>Date-picker with max date</h4>
       <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
 <md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

JS

```
   angular.module('MyApp').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.myDate = new Date();
      $scope.maxDate = new Date();
   });
```

i have created a pen to demo it

http://codepen.io/alwinpa/pen/EVzaMZ/

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens in my Firefox is that you can only select once. After that, it becomes unresponsive. I don't see anything wrong. Maybe a date-picker bug?

Comment: Yes its unresponsive when a date is selected from the first row, for me the lower end rows are also unresponsive initially. Might be a datepicker bug, but it seems to work with the demo in angular material documentation.

Comment: Using the element picker from the dev tools in Firefox it looks like the `div.md-virtual-repeat-offsetter` parent element is somehow in top of the last rows

Comment: the problem seems to be gone. tested on firefox 49, angular-material 1.x series